# Laravel Resource - Get data from relation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel's resources & Collection to build a small API.

I would like to recover all the posts of the categories

My relation on my model :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category');
}
```

Category controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return (new CategoryCollection(CategoryResource::collection($categories)));
}
```

My categoryResource :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'   => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'slug' => $this->slug
    ];
}
```

My CategoryCollection

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts')),
    ];
}
```

I try to recover the posts of a category first. When I make the following command I get an error: **Method ... relationLoaded does not exist**

`'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts'))`

What did I not understand?

I also created two PostCollection and PostResource files (basic, I did not modify them)

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index()

{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return (CategoryResource::collection($categories));
}
```

this is might help , try this

and if you want to use posts resource 
you need make posts resources 
and inside the CategoryResource

```
'posts'=>PostResource::collection($this->posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

cannot use Resource in Collection.
Use this

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return (new CategoryCollection($categories));
}
```